# How to generate dynamically a web page in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

How stackoverflow is generating a web page whenever a new question is asked by users. I need to generate  a php file with the name provided by users data.

Comment: You start by reading a few tutorials and the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Comment: It uses a MySQL(or any other) database to store question content, author, rate, etc in a table

Comment: A tutorial and some study is in order here. See my profile for one that should help.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow doesn't create a new page for each question, just like Facebook doesn't create a page per profile, group and things like that.

If you look at the URL in the address bar of your browser, you'll see something like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679474/how-to-generate-dynamically-a-web-page-in-php
```

It's always the same URL (stackoverflow.com/questions/) with a new ID right after that points to a question. In this case it's using the URL rewriting to make the URL prettier (and a few other things), but that's not required.

There is only one "questions" page, and it's looking at the ID in the URL, fetching the proper data and showing it. This isn't complicated to do, any beginner's PHP tutorial should cover that.

In practice, you could have something like this :

```
URL : website.com/questions?id=123
```

And, in the `questions.php` page :

```
$id = $_GET['id']; //$id will contain 123
//Do some treatment (ex: SQL query) with the ID in it
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id";
```

This is a very basic, no-security example, but it's just to show you how it works in principle.

Comment: can you explain in detail "URL rewriting to make the URL prettier " with example.

Comment: Search on Google for "URL rewriting", there are many tutorials.

Example : https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/